# ASP.NET receives null object from angular

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, typescript

I have a form inside my Angular web app and I'm sending a post request to my ASP.NET API, inside the if statement of the function shown below all the code runs without any problem, but inside the else statement something goes wrong.

For some reason when I'm sending this post request (this from the else statement) ASP.NET receives a null object without any reason and this surprises me because the same code inside the if statement is correct and it doesn't have any problem.

**NOTE:** I tried printing the object inside angular and gives me the correct content. Also I see using chrome dev-tools that my app sending the correct object.

**My payload (dev tools):**

[image: My payload (dev tools)]

My Angular function:

```
createNewSchool(schoolData: SchoolModel, newAdminData: UserModel, existingAdminID: number) {

        const headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'};
        
        if (existingAdminID == null || existingAdminID == -1) {

            // Create new school admin before creating school            
            const adminBody = newAdminData;
            this.http.post<any>(this.baseUrl + "Api/CreateUser", adminBody, { headers }).subscribe(response => {

                if (response.userID != null && response.userID != -1) {

                    // Set admin ID and create new school
                    schoolData.AdminId = response.userID;
                    const schoolBody = schoolData

                    this.http.post<any>(this.baseUrl + "Api/CreateSchool", schoolBody, { headers }).subscribe(schoolResponse => {
                        
                        if (schoolResponse) {
                            this.router.navigate(['/home']);
                        }

                    }, error => console.error(error));
                
                } else console.error("SERVER ERROR")

            }, error => console.error(error));

            
        } else {
            
            // Set admin ID to object and create new school
            schoolData.AdminId = existingAdminID;
            const schoolBody = schoolData;
            
            this.http.post<any>(this.baseUrl + "Api/CreateSchool", schoolBody, { headers }).subscribe(response => {
                
                if (response) {
                    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
                }

            }, error => console.error(error));
        }
    
    }
```

My ASP.NET controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Api/CreateSchool")]
public bool CreateNewSchool([FromBody] SchoolModel schoolData)
{
    SchoolManager context = HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(SchoolManager)) as SchoolManager;
    return context.CreateNewSchool(schoolData);
}
```

Comment: Did you try putting a breakpoint on the first line to check if it is null indeed, or is it in the `CreateNewSchool` that you found it null.

Comment: @AMunim i check it, the object is null

Comment: May try to share your request payload for sending the request to `CreateNewSchool` API in the `else` statement part. Thanks.

Comment: @YongShun Done, check it out!

Comment: Idk if that is the case but could you add the `[Consumes("application/json")]` attribute to receive `application/json`,  and to debug can you change `SchoolModel` to object then check if the variable `schoolData` has something, if it is not null after changing it to object then the problem is the mapping or binding between what are you sending and what are you trying to received

Comment: i think , API SchoolData model property should be same as Angular payload properties 
can you please share c# model of School data and angular side of model , 
it may help to figure out the issue